# Prevent MySQL from duplicates per given project

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

I have this MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE `d_hits` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `projectId` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `data` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `extras` text,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'notDone',
  `evaluation` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'NONE',
  `isGoldenHIT` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `goldenHITResultId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `notes` text,
  `created_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `isURL` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3561574 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My goal here is to prevent the database from creating duplicates `data` for a given project. For example, project with `projectID: 123` has `data: link1` but if I enter `data: link1` again it should prevent it from entering. However if `projectID is 333` and the given `data is again link1`, it should insert it without any problems. My question is, how can I prevent the duplicates per project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a unique constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE d_hits
            ADD UNIQUE (projectid,
                        data);
```